# How to compute $(\omega\wedge \tau)(X_1\wedge \ldots\wedge \widehat{X_j}\wedge \ldots\wedge X_{p+q+1})$?

Tags: combinatorics, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $C^\infty(M)$ be the associated algebra of smooth functions $f:M\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ with the pointwise operations. Define: $$\mathfrak{X}(M)=\{X\in \mathsf{End}_{\mathbb R}(C^\infty(M)): X(fg)=X(f)g+fX(g)\}\quad \textrm{and}\quad \Omega^k(M)=\Lambda^k \mathfrak{X}(M). $$ Both of these are $C^\infty(M)$-modules.

We can define a product $$\wedge:\Omega^p(M)\times \Omega^q(M)\longrightarrow \Omega^{p+q}(M)$$ setting: $$(\omega\wedge \tau)(X_1\wedge\ldots \wedge X_{k+l}):=\sum_{\sigma\mathsf{Sh}(p, q)} \mathsf{sgn}(\sigma) \omega(X_{\sigma(1)}\wedge \ldots\wedge X_{\sigma(p)})\tau(X_{\sigma(p+1)}\wedge \ldots \wedge X_{\sigma(p+q)}),$$ where $$\mathsf{Sh}(p, q):=\{\sigma\in\mathsf{S}_{p+q}: \sigma(1)<\ldots <\sigma(p)\quad \textrm{and}\quad \sigma(p+1)<\ldots<\sigma(p+q)\},$$ and where $S_{p+q}$ is the group of bijections of $\{1, \ldots, p+q\}$.

Let us fix $j\in \{1, \ldots, p\}$. How to compute $$(\omega\wedge \tau)(X_1\wedge \ldots\wedge \widehat{X_j}\wedge \ldots\wedge X_{p+q+1}),$$ where $\widehat{X_j}$ means to omit $X_j$.

The point is that we must compute $$(\omega\wedge \tau)(X_1\wedge\ldots\wedge X_{j-1}\wedge X_{j+1}\wedge \ldots\wedge X_{p+q+1}),$$ and I don't know how to deal very well with the lack of $X_j$.

I tried to make the change of variables $$Y_i=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl} 
X_i & \textrm{if} & 1\leq i\leq j-1\\
X_{i+1} & \textrm{if} & j\leq i\leq p+q
\end{array}\right.,$$ so that $$Y_{\sigma(i)}=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl} 
X_{\sigma(i)} & \textrm{if} & 1\leq \sigma(i)\leq j-1\\
X_{\sigma(i)+1} & \textrm{if} & j\leq \sigma(i)\leq p+q
\end{array}\right.$$ but it doesn't seem to help. Furthermore, the image of $\sigma(i)$ could be $j$ and that can't be.

Thanks.

Comment: I would deform $Sh(p,q)$ to $Sh(p,q,i)=\{\tau \circ \sigma: \sigma \in Sh(p,q)\}$ and $\tau (i)=i$ if $i<j$ and $\tau (i)=i+1$ if $i\geq j$

Comment: Indeed, I had already done that, but I didn't know how to move on with the computations after that.

Comment: $\tau$ is a map between which sets?

Comment: $\tau:[p+q]\longrightarrow [p+q+1]\setminus \{j\}$
Well i guess it's the same, so, for example 
$X_1 \wedge X_2 \wedge X_4 \wedge X_5$ under $\sigma = 2314$ where $\tau = 1245$ then $\tau \circ \sigma = 2415$ which goes to what one expects.